# how to get rootWeb URL of the site collection

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, csom

I'm trying to get the top level site URL by using C# CSOM. 
i have site like below

```
 (http://test.sharepoint.com/aaa/bbbb)
```

i am trying to get the rootWeb like below?

```
(http://test.sharepoint.com)
```

how do i get this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Uri.DnsSafeHost` property to get the root web of the tenant.

Modify the below mentioned sample code:

```
private string GetRootSite(string site)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(site.TrimEnd(new[] { '/' }));

    // using old string.Format method
    // return string.Format("{0}://{1}",uri.Scheme,uri.DnsSafeHost);
    // or using the new $"{}" notation
    return $"{uri.Scheme}://{uri.DnsSafeHost}";
}

public void DoSomeStuff()
{   
    string siteUrl = "http://test.sharepoint.com/aaa/bbbb";
    string rootWebUrl = GetRootSite(siteUrl);
    //do some stuff with root web url
}
```

Reference - [Uri.DnsSafeHost property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.dnssafehost?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Uri_DnsSafeHost)

Answer (score 3):

In .Net managed client code, you can use following method:

```
public static string GetRootweb()
{
    string rootweb = string.Empty;
    using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://test.sharepoint.com/aaa/bbbb"))
    {
        context.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
        context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(GetSPOAccountName(), GetSPOSecureStringPassword());
        context.Load(context.Site.RootWeb, w => w.Url, w => w.Title);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        rootweb ="Root Web URL:: "+ context.Site.RootWeb.Url +" Title:: "+ context.Site.RootWeb.Title;             
    }
    return rootweb;
}
```

> Note: `GetSPOAccountName` & `GetSPOSecureStringPassword` is the method to get user name and password to authenticate client context.

[Here](http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Articles/Details/how-to-retrieve-root-web-site-url-from-site-collection-21990.aspx) is the referral article.

Comment: Hi Pardip,
thank you for your quick response.
but am getting current site URL only
http://test.sharepoint.com/aaa/bbbb/

Answer (score 0):

You can use REST API to get to the root site. Try this below endpoint in your browser. Append this after your site URL -

```
 /_api/site/rootweb?$select=Title,ServerRelativeUrl,URL
```

To get just the URL, try this (specific to your example) -

```
http://test.sharepoint.com/aaa/bbbb/_api/site/rootweb?$select=URL
```